# Using Values from Location Manager Function in other functions

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, location, cllocationmanager

I'm trying to extract latitude and longitude from the location manager function to then present in an UITableView. I want it to update the TableView as the location updates. But the `Collect` Array is still empty?
How can I do this?
Any input would be greatly appreciated!

Here's my code:

```
class ThirdViewController: UIViewController, CLLocationManagerDelegate, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource{
    @IBOutlet weak var map: MKMapView!
    @IBOutlet var Tableview: UIView!

    let manager = CLLocationManager()
    var Collect = [Double]()

    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
        let location = locations[0]
        let span:MKCoordinateSpan = MKCoordinateSpanMake(0.01,0.01) //shows the size of map screen
        let myLocation:CLLocationCoordinate2D = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(location.coordinate.latitude,location.coordinate.longitude)
        let region:MKCoordinateRegion = MKCoordinateRegionMake(myLocation, span)
        map.setRegion(region, animated: true)
        self.map.showsUserLocation = true

        let lat = (location.coordinate.latitude)
        let long = (location.coordinate.longitude)
        Collect.append(lat)
        Collect.append(long)
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return Collect.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = UITableViewCell(style: UITableViewCellStyle.default, reuseIdentifier: "TableCell")
            cell.textLabel?.text = Collect[indexPath.row]
        return cell
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        manager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
        manager.startUpdatingLocation()
        super.viewDidLoad()
        print(Collect)
    }
```

Comment: You need to reload the table after each update.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
class ThirdViewController: UIViewController, CLLocationManagerDelegate, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource{

@IBOutlet weak var map: MKMapView!
@IBOutlet var Tableview: UIView!

let manager = CLLocationManager()
var Collect = NSMutableArray()
var filterArr = NSArray()

func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
    let location = locations[0]
    let span:MKCoordinateSpan = MKCoordinateSpanMake(0.01,0.01) //shows the size of map screen
    let myLocation:CLLocationCoordinate2D = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(location.coordinate.latitude,location.coordinate.longitude)
    let region:MKCoordinateRegion = MKCoordinateRegionMake(myLocation, span)
    map.setRegion(region, animated: true)
    self.map.showsUserLocation = true


    let lat = String(location.coordinate.latitude)
    let long = String(location.coordinate.longitude)
    Collect.append(lat)
    Collect.append(long)
    filterArr = Collect as NSMutableArray()
    Tableview.reloadData()


}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return Collect.count
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = UITableViewCell(style: UITableViewCellStyle.default, reuseIdentifier: "TableCell")
        cell.textLabel?.text = Collect[indexPath.row]
    return cell
}




override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    manager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
    manager.startUpdatingLocation()
    super.viewDidLoad()
    Tableview.delegate = self
    Tableview.datasource = self
    print(Collect)
}
```

Comment: Why did you change the code to use non-Swift arrays? That's not appropriate. Use Swift collections in Swift code. And why convert the numbers to strings in the collection? That's not appropriate. Keep the raw data. Only convert data to strings when the data needs to be displayed.